# Unable to connect to EC2 with keypair

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

`EC2 dashboard` -> `Network & Security` -> `Key Pairs`

creates a key pair that gets automatically downloaded

---

On running below command:

`ssh -i ./central-region-keypair rancher@$AWS_PUBLIC_IP`

I get password prompt.

**Edit:**

After running below command:

```
$ aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-e42e9480 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name central-region-keypair --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=os,Value=rancheros}]' --user-data "$(cat cloud-config.yml)"
```

EC2 instance gets created.

but ssh client still cannot connect to EC2

```
$ ssh rancher@$AWS_PUBLIC_IP
The authenticity of host 'xx.xx.xx.xx(xx.xx.xx.xx)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:2l6666666666666666pKWOLBAsktyZbqYk4.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'xx.xx.xx.xx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
rancher@xx.xx.xx.xx's password:
```

Debug:

```
$ ssh -vvv rancher@$AWS_PUBLIC_IP
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "xx.xx.xx.xx" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx [xx.xx.xx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Ubuntu-10
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Ubuntu-10 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to xx.xx.xx.xx:22 as 'rancher'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:19
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from xx.xx.xx.xx
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:2lhr4yhS91BsZk6wzBCJX9nUhmpKWOLBAsktyZbqYk4
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:19
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from xx.xx.xx.xx
debug1: Host 'xx.xx.xx.xx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:19
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: sham@dockerBuildAzureVM (0x558a246feb50), agent
debug2: key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:l4lTex0000000000000000000000IZhE/PrSGhs sham@dockerBuildAzureVM
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
rancher@xx.xx.xx.xx's password: 

user1@user1:~$
```

---

Why ssh prompt's for password, despite using keypair?

Comment: Did you specify that the EC2 instance use that key when you initially created the EC2 instance?

Comment: @MarkB I ran this command `aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-e42e9480 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=os,Value=rancheros}]' --user-data "$(cat cloud-config.yml)"`

Answer (score 1):

You needed to specify the key pair for the instance to use when you created the instance.

From [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html):

```
--key-name (string)
```

The name of the key pair. You can create a key pair using CreateKeyPair or ImportKeyPair .

> **Warning** If you do not specify a key pair, you can't connect to the
>   instance unless you choose an AMI that is configured to allow users
>   another way to log in.

Comment: @overexchange key name is not the same thing as the path to the local key file. It should be the name of the keypair, as listed in the AWS console.

Comment: try running in verbose mode with `ssh -vvv` to see what it says about the key file. You might need to adjust your local key file permissions.

Comment: Is `-i` option mandatory? because the trainer in online course is not using `-i` option. Debugs are uploaded in query

Comment: `-i` specifies that the next argument is the path to the keyfile. You can't pass a keyfile without `-i`.

Comment: It is possible to use `ssh-add` to cache a keypair, so that it doesn't need to be provided each time. That might be what the trainer did previously.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein what is the syntax to add keypair?

Comment: [ssh-add program - Usage, ssh-agent, SSH keys | SSH.COM](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/add)